# How use a variable to add value to the innertext in Selenium java?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am using the below code:
content here is variable.

```
content = "Hello";
js.executeScript("document.all('rtf_text_800890007').innerText = '" + content + "'; return true; ");
```

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript? (They're not remotely related.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below for updating the innertext of the element by JavaScriptExecutor-

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="yourtext"
```

OR

You can take the below query as a reference which is used to change the attribute of an element to highlight it in the dom.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", 
element, "color: black; border: 4px solid red;");
```